# Get the default values of table columns in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, default

I'm looking for a way to run a query to find the default values of the columns of a table in Postgres. For example, if I made a table with the following query:

<sub>**Editor's note: I fixed the table definition as it has no impact on the question.</sub>

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    integer int DEFAULT 2,
    text varchar(64) DEFAULT 'I am default',
    moretext varchar(64) DEFAULT 'I am also default',
    unimportant int 
);
```

I need a query that would tell me, in some format, that the default for `integer` is 2, `text` is 'I am default', and `moretext` is 'I am also default'. The query result can include any value for any other column that doesn't have a default, i.e., `unimportant` is unimportant for my purposes and doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 69):

Use the information schema:

```
SELECT column_name, column_default
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE (table_schema, table_name) = ('public', 'mytable')
ORDER BY ordinal_position;

 column_name │             column_default             
─────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────
 integer     │ 2
 text        │ 'I am default'::character varying
 moretext    │ 'I am also default'::character varying
 unimportant │ 
(4 rows)
```

Up to the schema naming, this should work in any SQL database system.

Comment: This works, but it should be noted that if performance is a concern, this query will most likely perform worse for you than the answer provided by Erwin.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name should is not must

Answer (score 33):

[System catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html) are the source of truth in Postgres:

```sql
SELECT pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) AS default_value
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute    a
LEFT   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d ON (a.attrelid, a.attnum) = (d.adrelid, d.adnum)
WHERE  NOT a.attisdropped           -- no dropped (dead) columns
AND    a.attnum   > 0               -- no system columns
AND    a.attrelid = 'myschema.mytable'::regclass
AND    a.attname  = 'mycolumn';
```

- [Related answer on dba.SE discussing **information schema vs. system catalogs**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75124/3684)

`LEFT JOIN` guarantees a result as long as the column exists. If there is no default you get `NULL` - which happens to be the *default* default. And almost always correct. But see:

- [How to use default value of data type as column default?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212253/3684)

**To exclude** columns without default, use `JOIN` instead and be prepared to get no row occasionally.

The special cast `::regclass` considers the current setting for `search_path`. With names that aren't schema-qualified (which you should, to be sure!), you may or may not get the expected result. See rebuttal below. [More in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) Related:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

No need to include `pg_class` once we have the OID of the table. Faster without.

#### Why the first answer wouldn't do

[@Zohaib's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8146499/939860) is almost but not quite right. There are a couple of issues. I copied it here for future reference. **Do not use this**:

```sql
SELECT adsrc as default_value
 FROM pg_attrdef pad, pg_atttribute pat, pg_class pc
 WHERE pc.relname='your_table_name'
     AND pc.oid=pat.attrelid AND pat.attname='your_column_name'
     AND pat.attrelid=pad.adrelid AND pat.attnum=pad.adnum
```

- Copied from some blog. Good that it's mentioned, but the source should be added. People reading that blog need to be warned.
- Typo in `pg_atttribute` - fixed easily.
- Doesn't return any rows, if there is no default specified for the requested column. Better make that a `LEFT JOIN  pg_attrdef ON ..`, so you *always* get a resulting row if the column exists. It will be NULL, if there is no default, which is actually the correct result because `NULL` **is** the default then.
- If you remove `attname` from the `WHERE` clause, you only get values for columns that actually have a default value. Not for others. And you need to add `attname` to the `SELECT` list or you will not know for which column.
- The query would also return the default of a column that is already dropped, which is **wrong**. Read about the [details in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html).
- Most importantly: the query can give **completely wrong** results, as it does not take the schema name into account. There can be any number of `table1.col1` in a postgres database: in various schemas. If more than one have a default, you get multiple values. If the column you have in mind does not have a default, but another one in another schema does, you will be fooled and never know it.
- Last not least: in recent PostgreSQL releases, the `adsrc` column [has been removed](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=fe5038236c6b99d48c2faa2247b5cec9703add2a) from `pg_attrdef` by commit fe5038236c, as it was redundant, deprecated and unused in PostgreSQL.

To sum it up: C/P from some blog without insight went dangerously wrong.

Comment: Thanks - very useful, but I noticed even with `WHERE NOT a.attisdropped` you still get occasional columns named `"........pg.dropped.30........"` etc.

Comment: I would like to wrap this query in a function, but what data type should the function should return, since the returned value will depend on the type of the requested column?

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON: Use data type `text`. [`pg_get_expression()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) returns `text`. Also note some updates above.

Answer (score 2):

I liked [Erwin's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8148177/1571426) but was having some difficulties:

1. Sometimes I would get column names "........pg.dropped.30.......", etc. even with the `NOT a.attisdropped` qualification. It was not consistent, I wound up having to loop through the results and check the column names.
2. The returned default value sometimes had a cast attached, e.g. `'I am default'::character varying` which did not work when they are being stuffed into web form input values. I could not think of a good way to remove the cast suffix without doing something like `.replace(/::.*/, '')` which is not robust enough. I bet Erwin can figure out some magical way to [`EVAL()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7433201/1571426) the returned value and use the `a.atttypid` column to get the right data type.

So I went back to what I was doing before:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO mytable DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING *;
ROLLBACK;
```

One thing to note here is that any `SERIAL` columns will get incremented. It likely does not matter so long as it is unique if it is just a table index. Otherwise it is a deal breaker.

The other thing to watch out for is any `TRIGGER AFTER/BEFORE INSERT` which will fire even though the `INSERT` gets rolled back (I think any changes the trigger function makes will get rolled back though.)

Answer (score 0):

you can just type " \d table_name" command , then It will displays some information about the
table, such  as  the default value of a column.

**--create table**

```
skytf=> CREATE TABLE mytable (
skytf(>     a integer DEFAULT 2,
skytf(>     b varchar(64)  DEFAULT 'I am default',
skytf(>     c varchar(64)  DEFAULT 'I am also default'
skytf(> );
CREATE TABLE
```

**--show table information**

```
skytf=> \d mytable
                              Table "skytf.mytable"
 Column |         Type          |                   Modifiers                    
--------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------
 a      | integer               | default 2
 b      | character varying(64) | default 'I am default'::character varying
 c      | character varying(64) | default 'I am also default'::character varying
```

Comment: He asked for how to *query* for the default value. This post answers a question that's not asked. (It's also horribly formatted, but that's unrelated to the downvote)

Comment: \d will show the default values of a column . I post this answer just because it's easier than query pg_catalog tables or views.

Comment: Users will not always have access to the psql-interface (web hotel customers, for example). \d is therefor not always available, while pg_catalog is.

Comment: run psql with -E and see the query it used to get the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I'm spending some time trying to get to grips with the pg_catalog tables. I'm assuming the names and such come back from the days when letters had to be carved individually and were, consequently, very expensive ;-) Anyway, that's all a fact of life. I wanted to get the default value for a column and ran into this thread. I saw a mention of wanting to have Erwin Brandstetter's code as a function. I've wrapped it up and figured I'd add it to the archives:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.column_default (qualified_name text, column_name text)
  RETURNS text
 AS $$

SELECT d.adsrc AS default_value -- A human-readable representation of the default value, already typed as text.
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
LEFT   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d ON (a.attrelid, a.attnum)
                                     = (d.adrelid,  d.adnum)
WHERE  NOT a.attisdropped   -- no dropped (dead) columns
AND    a.attnum > 0         -- no system columns
AND    a.attrelid = qualified_name::regclass
AND    a.attname = column_name;

$$ LANGUAGE sql;

ALTER FUNCTION data.column_default (qualified_name text, column_name text) OWNER TO user_bender;
```

I'm using the code (probably in an inhumane manner) like so:

```
select pg_class.relnamespace::regnamespace as schema_name,
        attrelid::regclass as parent_name,
        attname,
       format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) as data_type,
       column_default(attrelid::regclass::text,attname),
       attnum

 from pg_attribute
 left join pg_class on (pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid::regclass)
```

From here I figure I'll write a view, etc., once I know better what I'm really after. For now, I'm using a CTE as a temporary view:

```
with attributes as
(select pg_class.relnamespace::regnamespace as schema_name,
        attrelid::regclass as parent_name,
        attname,
       format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) as data_type,
       column_default(attrelid::regclass::text,attname),
       attnum

 from pg_attribute
 left join pg_class on (pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid::regclass)
)

select *
  from attributes
 where parent_name::text = 'sales'
```

Corrections, improvements, and suggestions all welcome...I'm just getting my feet wet in pg_catalog.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT column_default FROM information_schema.columns WHERE
table_name='your_table_name';

in case:

SELECT column_default FROM information_schema.columns WHERE
table_name='your_table_name' AND schema='whatever_schema';

found the answer here: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4558AA88.3070102@brainscraps.com

Comment: This doesn't seem to add much to the answer posted 10 years earlier.

Answer (score -2):

```
 SELECT adsrc as default_value
 FROM pg_attrdef pad, pg_atttribute pat, pg_class pc
 WHERE pc.relname='your_table_name'
     AND pc.oid=pat.attrelid AND pat.attname='your_column_name'
     AND pat.attrelid=pad.adrelid AND pat.attnum=pad.adnum
```

I found this query for postgresql on one of the blogs. you can try this to check if it works. To get values of all coumns, you can try removing `AND pat.attname='your_column_name'` from where clause.

Comment: ERROR:  relation "pg_atttribute" does not exist