# Where are default values for a particular row stored in amazon redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to convert Redshift table to a JSON so that sql queries can be automatically generated from this JSON. For this I need datatypes, column names distkey and sortkey which are available in some or other format in system tables. One thing I couldn't find out is how to extract default values of a redshift column.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer your question: [Get the default values of table columns in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146448/get-the-default-values-of-table-columns-in-postgres)

Summary:

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS works well if you only have one schema. It gets trickier if you have several tables with the same name across schemas.

This works in all cases:

```
SELECT d.adsrc AS default_value
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
LEFT   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d ON (a.attrelid, a.attnum)
                                     = (d.adrelid,  d.adnum)
WHERE  NOT a.attisdropped   -- no dropped (dead) columns
AND    a.attnum > 0         -- no system columns
AND    a.attrelid = 'myschema.mytable'::regclass
AND    a.attname = 'mycolumn';
```

I'm using a slightly different version in production to also get the type (and length when appropriate of each column):

```
SELECT
            pg_namespace.nspname AS schema_name,
            pg_class.relname AS table_name,
            pg_attribute.attname AS column_name,
            pg_type.typname AS type,
            pg_attribute.atttypmod AS column_len,
            pg_attrdef.adsrc AS column_default
FROM
            pg_class
INNER JOIN
            pg_namespace
            ON pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid
INNER JOIN
            pg_attribute
            ON pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid
INNER JOIN
            pg_type
            ON pg_attribute.atttypid = pg_type.oid
LEFT JOIN 
            pg_attrdef  
            ON pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_attrdef.adrelid
            AND pg_attribute.attnum = pg_attrdef.adnum
WHERE
            pg_class.relname = 'table_name'
            AND pg_namespace.nspname = 'schema_name'
            AND pg_type.typname NOT IN ('oid','xid','tid','cid')
            AND pg_attribute.attnum >= 0
ORDER BY
            pg_attribute.attnum ASC
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Redshift is almost same as postgresql. Using it, you may get the column's default from table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

I have checked it in postgre:

```
create table test_tbl (n int DEFAULT 100500);

select table_name, column_name, column_default from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'test_tbl';

 table_name | column_name | column_default 
------------+-------------+----------------
 test_tbl   | n           | 100500
```