# Insert the default value, if variable is null

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table `t` with the column `c`. The column `c` has a default value.

```
create table t (c text default 'a');
```

I can insert the default value.

```
insert into t (c) values (default);
```

Now I want to do insert the value of a variable into the table. And if the variable is null, I want to insert the default value.

```
do $$declare
  v text;
begin
  insert into t (c) values (coalesce (v, default));
end$$;
```

But It does not work.

> ERROR:  DEFAULT is not allowed in this context

How to work around this? Do I need two different insert statements?

Comment: You could query the default value for that column (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146448/get-the-default-values-of-table-columns-in-postgres) and use that value in stead of `default`.