# How to determine whether a row contains a default value in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I know that you can use `= DEFAULT` in `UPDATE` statements, e.g.

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET some_column = DEFAULT
WHERE id = 1;
```

Is it possible to look for defaults in a `SELECT` statement? e.g.

```sql
SELECT id FROM my_table
WHERE some_column = DEFAULT;
```

That specific syntax gives the error "DEFAULT is not allowed in this context."

Comment: In general the `DEFAULT` value is defined only for `DML` as it could be e.g. `now()` which has no meaning in `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do that, and since a column's `DEFAULT` value can be an expression, it would be difficult to fake.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8153081/4808122) shows how to get the DEFAULT value stored in the information_schema.

The problem is that the default value is stored as text, so you see e.g. a string `'hello'::text` or *expression* `(1 + 1)` which is difficult to compare  with the column value.

Anyway you may use a trick using a helper table illustrated below.

*Create table*

```
create table mytable (
id int ,
col text default 'hello',
col2 int default 1,
col3 int
);
```

*and put some data in it*

```
insert into mytable(id) values(1);
insert into mytable(id,col,col2,col3) values(2,'x',3,10);
```

*now create a clone table (`like`) and insert one row with DEFAULT values*

```
drop table get_default;
create table get_default ( like mytable including all);
insert into get_default DEFAULT VALUES;
```

*query is trivial only you must hanle the case of `null` default value in extra `OR` predicate*

```
select * from   mytable
where col3 = (select col3 from get_default) or
col3 is null and (select col3 from get_default) is null;

id|col  |col2|col3|
--+-----+----+----+
 1|hello|   1|    |
```

But note that your approach **will fail badly** if you use **non deterministic** DEFAULT values such as `now()` or `nextval`.

Comment: That certainly works. Would it make sense to `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE get_default`?

Comment: Depends on your use case. If you need the table only in the current session or transaction - then why not to use a `temporary table`? @Bbrk24