# Aggregating rows into JSON hash

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I have the following table:

```
roles

id |  name | person
---+-------+--------
1  | admin | jon
2  | admin | fred
3  | user  | alfred
4  | user  | jon
```

Where name can vary to any value.

I'd like to get a JSON hash like so:

```
{"admin": ["jon", "fred"], "user": ["alfred", "jon"]}
```

Using PL/PGSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna assume the name's can vary cause without it it's no challenge.
Usins the [eval function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7433644/2115135):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eval(expression text) RETURNS text
AS
$body$
DECLARE
  result text;
BEGIN
  execute expression INTO RESULT;
  RETURN result;
END;
$body$
language plpgsql
```

We can create a dynamic crosstab:

```
SELECT eval('SELECT row_to_json(q)
FROM (SELECT '||(SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT '"'||name||'"',',')
                 FROM roles)||'
      FROM crosstab(''SELECT 1,name,array_agg(person)::text[]
                      FROM roles
                      GROUP BY name;
                    '') as ct(row_name int,'||(SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT '"'||name||'"                   text[]',',')
FROM roles)||')
)as q');
```

### EDIT

Less fancy aproach:

```
SELECT '{'||string_agg(temp,',')||'}'
FROM
(
SELECT '"'||name||'": ['||(string_agg(person,',')::text)||']' as temp FROM roles GROUP BY name
) as q
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, I'll see what I can do with it.

Comment: I tried your approach and it works, but performances are terrible. I am currently investigating a way to improve app performance (JSON generation is in ruby right now), I should have mentioned performances requirements. I will still accept your answer as it does answer my question.

Comment: @NicolasGoy I think I may have gotten a bit carried away with that crosstab. The query I added now should perform much better.

Comment: I'll look at what 9.3 proposes, but your solution still works for now.

Answer (score 1):

The current development version - future 9.3 - of postgres will put a strong focus on JSON support inside the database. Depending on how fast you need a solution for this problem you could wait for 9.3 or install the current beta (which should include the new features).

Here are two articles regarding the new json features - first is third party - second is the JSON lib reference on the dev tree:

- [postgres 9.3 features highligh json](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-3-feature-highlight-json-operators/)
- [postgres devel json lib](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-json.html)