# python's eval() in Amazon-Redshift: evaluating strings as expressions

Tags: eval, amazon-redshift

My strong conviction is that no solution for this exists, but I thought I'd ask anyways. My question is precisely this one:

[Are there any way to execute a query inside the string value (like eval) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433201/are-there-any-way-to-execute-a-query-inside-the-string-value-like-eval-in-post)

But for Amazon Redshift, which does not support stored functions. Specifically, I believe my expressions can all be evaluated as Booleans with one or more expressions such as 'X <= 10' concatenated with ANDs and ORs, i.e.:

```
string = 'X <= 10 AND Y = 5 AND Z >= 0'
```

I can easily replace into the variables with the correct values but am trying not to resort to building my own parser. Anyone see a nice way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck! Amazon Redshift [recently introduced User Defined Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/user-defined-functions-for-amazon-redshift/) that can call Python code.

Therefore, you can take advantage of the Python `eval()` command to evaluate a condition.

Here's some code that worked for me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_eval(condition TEXT)
RETURNS boolean
VOLATILE AS $$
return eval(condition)
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Then run it with:

```
SELECT f_eval('5 < 6 and 3 < 4');
```

This returns `true` in SQL.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the tip.