# Eval Calculation-string: "2 * 3 + 4 * 5" in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, eval

I would like to evaluate a pure-calculation **string** in Postgres.

For example: `eval('234 + 65 * 3')`

The function is NOT constant, so could also simply be `2 + 2`

Expecting something like `SELECT eval('2 + 2') AS result`

I read about huge security issues regarding `eval()` functions, but those seem to incorporate `SELECT` statements. Here pure calculation requirements.

Comment: What's the point of the eval? Why not just `SELECT 2 + 2 AS result`?

Comment: The string is calculated dynamically, using regexp and results from other queries.. If not.. why would I ask this question..

Comment: See  this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433201/are-there-any-way-to-execute-a-query-inside-the-string-value-like-eval-in-post

Comment: @OtoShavadze Thanks, I've seen that, but this worries me: "Also bear in mind that this opens a huge security risk" That's part of my question, is there something safe for pure calculations..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `PL/pgSQL`:

```
create or replace function f(_s text)
returns numeric as $$
declare i numeric;
begin
    execute format('select %s', _s) into i;
    return i;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select f('1 + 1');
 f 
---
 2
```

Comment: Exactly! No security issues here? Would there be a need to scan the string for words like "select" or "insert"?

Comment: @kvdmolen security is a big issue here. f.ex. calling `f('id from (delete from users returning *) s limit 1')` *might* run (and there is no `select` in it).

Comment: @pozs Yes indeed.. would something like this work you think? `EXECUTE format('SELECT %s', replace(replace(_s, 'delete',''),'select','')) INTO i;` So, replacing the words `select` and `delete` with `''`. It's not sweet, but at least it will return an error.

Comment: @kvdmolen if you really only have formulas, try validating it with regex instead (before executing) f.ex. `_s ~ '^[\s\d\.\+\-\*/\(\)]+$'`