# Use output of case as a condition in Select query

Tags: postgresql, delta-lake

Just curious if I could run the below as a single SQL select statement without using procedural language (procedure, function, anonymous block).

```
with cte as (select ' and 1=1' as col1)
select 'test' 
where 2=2 
and case when 1=1 then (select col1 from cte) end;
```

I get the below error

```
ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type text
LINE 4: and case when 1=1 then (select col1 from cte) end;
```

which obviously means the result of the `CASE` statement is assumed to be a text value rather than the actual condition.

The reason I want this is I want to run the query in DeltaLake where I can't use procedural language. Only Select statements are possible. `col1` in the `CTE` can be a different `AND` condition for different inputs.

I am trying this query in `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: The result of the CASE statement is assumed to be a text value because it is a text value: `select ' and 1=1' as col1`. Check it with `select pg_typeof((select ' and 1=1' as col1))`. The result of 'inserting' the cte will be `...where 2=2 and when 1=1 then ' and 1=1' end...`. How about inserting the condition directly?

Comment: @hobgoblin yes it is text. But is it possible to make it an expression in the SELECT query?
I cannot insert the condition directly because both the column name and the value in the where clause are dynamic. Even the operator can be 'OR' or 'AND' or 'LIKE' or 'NOT LIKE' etc.

Comment: If you want to use dynamic queries without resorting to PL/pgSQL or some other procedural language, then consider using `QUERY_TO_XML`.

Comment: For dynamic SQL, you must assemble the query in a host language. PL/pgSQL is such a host language, or Java or python or whatever floats your boat.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433201/are-there-any-way-to-execute-a-query-inside-the-string-value-like-eval-in-post) for some inspiration.

Otherwise, the [query_to_xml()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-MAPPING) function mentioned by @John, might help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result without using procedural language, you can rewrite the query as follows:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT ' and 1=1' AS col1)
SELECT 'test'
WHERE 2 = 2
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM cte
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND 1 = 1
  );
```

Comment: This doesn't address the more general case of additional conditions as mentioned by the OP.